# Dagger inject not working for Retrofit

Tags: android, dependency-injection, retrofit, dagger-2

I am trying to use Dagger 2 for instantiating a Retrofit interface. The `CloudContactDataStore` class injects the `RestClient` and calls its methods.

When I instantiate a `CloudContactDataStore` object, its `RestClient` attribute has `null` value.

```
public class CloudContactDataStore implements ContactDataStore {

    @Inject RestClient restClient;

    public CloudContactDataStore() {
        this.initializeInjector();
    }

    private void initializeInjector() {
        DaggerApiComponent.builder()
                .apiModule(new ApiModule())
                .build()
                .inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<ContactEntity> contactLogin(String contactId) {
        return this.restClient.contactLogin(contactId); // Here restClient is null!
    }
}
```

Here is how I create the Dagger Module and Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApiModule.class)
public interface ApiComponent {
    void inject(ContactDataStore contactDataStore);
}

@Module
public class ApiModule {

    @Provides public RestClient provideRestClient(ApiService apiService) {
        return new RestClientImpl(apiService);
    }

    @Provides public ApiService provideApiService(RestAdapter restAdapter) {
        return restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
    }

    @Provides public RestAdapter provideRestAdapter() {
        return RestApiAdapter.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Now, the `RestClient` class and its implementation:

```
public interface RestClient {
    Observable<ContactEntity> contactLogin(String contactId);
}

public class RestClientImpl implements RestClient {

    ApiService apiService;

    @Inject
    public RestClientImpl(ApiService apiService) {
        this.apiService = apiService;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<ContactEntity> contactLogin(String contactId) {
        return apiService.login(contactId, "xxx-xxx-xxx");
    }
}
```

The `ApiService` interface is the Retrofit interface:

```
public interface ApiService {

    String API_BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.2";

    @POST("/login")
    Observable<ContactEntity> login(@Body String id, @Header("Key") String key);

}
```

And finally, the `RestApiAdapter`:

```
public class RestApiAdapter {

    private static RestAdapter sharedInstance = null;

    public static RestAdapter getInstance() {
        if (sharedInstance == null){


            sharedInstance = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .setEndpoint(ApiService.API_BASE_URL)
                    .build();
        }

        return sharedInstance;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How have you accessed your dagger component in activity or fragment?

Comment: An `Activity` calls a method of an object. That object instantiates `CloudContactDataStore` and calls `contactLogin` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has the same problem as in [Why Dagger inject is not working but component.getObject yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947791/why-dagger-inject-is-not-working-but-component-getobject-yes/32996581#32996581) and the same solution. That is you need to either change your `inject(ContactDataStore)` method to `inject(CloudContactDataStore)` so it can see the field that needs injecting, or you need to add a method in `ContactDataStore` that allows you to inject the method yourself.