# Why Dagger inject is not working but component.getObject yes

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying to use Dagger 2 for instantiating a Retrofit interface. The `CloudContactDataStore` class injects the `RestClient` and calls its methods.

When I instantiate a `CloudContactDataStore` object, its `RestClient` attribute has `null` value.

```
public class CloudContactDataStore implements ContactDataStore {

    @Inject RestClient restClient;

    public CloudContactDataStore() {
        this.initializeInjector();
    }

    private void initializeInjector() {
        ApiComponent component = DaggerApiComponent.builder()
            .apiModule(new ApiModule())
            .build();

        component.inject(this); // Nothing changes, restClient is null!

        this.restClient = component.getRestClient(); // This works
    }
}
```

Here is how I create the Dagger Module and Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApiModule.class)
public interface ApiComponent {
    void inject(ContactDataStore contactDataStore);

    RestClient getRestClient();
}

@Module
public class ApiModule {

    @Provides public RestClient provideRestClient(ApiService apiService) {
        return new RestClientImpl(apiService);
    }

    @Provides public ApiService provideApiService(RestAdapter restAdapter) {
        return restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
    }

    @Provides public RestAdapter provideRestAdapter() {
        return RestApiAdapter.getInstance();
    }
}
```

So, why the `inject` function does not work but calling `component`'s `getRestClient()` yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it's very useful to look at the code that Dagger 2 generates as it's quite easy to follow and can often point you in the right direction.

Dagger 2 creates code much like you'd write so think about how you would implement `ApiComponent.inject(ContactDataStore)`. Assuming within that method you had access to a RestClient how would you get it into the field? If you sat and wrote it you'd notice that you have to do something like this:

```
((CloudContactDataStore) contactDataStore).restClient = restClient;
```

Or in other words you'd need to cast it down to a specific implementation. Dagger 2 doesn't cast down, EVER (at least I've not seen it), because that is usually unsafe.

So, you have two choices. Change the `inject(ContactDataStore)` method to `inject(CloudContactDataStore)`, or provide a method on `ContactDataStore` that allows the `RestClient` to be passed in.

Update: Its not possible to @Inject through abstract, i.e. interface, method.

If you want to inject it through the `ContactDataStore` API then you have a problem as there is currently a restriction in Dagger 2 (have raised a feature request to remove it) that you cannot mark an abstract method with `@Inject`. So, in the meantime (or forever if there is some reason why it cannot work in Dagger 2) you will need to do it manually, i.e. get the instance of `RestClient` from your component method and pass it to the appropriate method on the interface.